# One hot encoding error "sort.list(y)..."

Tags: r, categorical-data, encoding

I'm trying to do one hot encoding on a data set containing 4 categorical features in R. Unique levels per feature:  400, 60, 6, 5, respectively. I get the following error during the first call to the ohe function (acm.disjonctif):

**Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?**

I can't do sorting on a per column basis because it will remove the data relationship between columns.  What am I missing in understanding?  I searched on the web but couldn't find anything helpful.

Here is the code I'm running in RStudio:

```
ohe_feats = c('RSN_CD', 'RSN_CAT', 'ELIG_SYS_CD', 'PROD_CD')
for (f in ohe_feats) {
    df_all_dummy = acm.disjonctif(as.factor(nodups[f]))   # package = ade4
    nodups[f] = NULL
    nodups = cbind(nodups, df_all_dummy)
}
```

Comment: What is `nodups`? And any particular reason you doing this in a loop and then cbinding the results together?

Answer (score 2):

I may be missing the point, but you don't need to do this one variable at a time in a loop and then bind the columns together - that's not the R way.  Here's an alternative:

```
# create some simulated data
n <- 10000
X <- data.frame(f_a_ = factor(sample(1:400, n, replace = TRUE)),
                f_b_ = factor(sample(1:60, n, replace = TRUE)),
                f_c_ = factor(sample(1:6, n, replace = TRUE)),
                f_d_ = factor(sample(1:5, n, replace = TRUE)),
                y = rep(1, n))

# use R's inbuilt understanding of formulas to do the "one hot encoding" for you
x_onehot <- model.matrix(y ~ ., data = X)
```